# How to consider "<return>" as an object in xml response in SOAP UI

Tags: xml, loops, groovy, soapui

Sorry if the tile is confusing, did not find better words to describe it. Basically i have a weird situation where i have one of my xml field as return and i am trying to iterate through that. Example below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns4:retrieveFoodsResponse>
         <return>
            <ns6:menuDetails>foo bar </ns6:menuDetails>
            <ns6:menuDetails>foo1 bar1</ns6:menuDetails>
         </return>
       </ns4:retrieveFoodsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
<soap:Enveloper>
```

Now i am trying to iterate through this using

```
def dessert= xml.Body.retrieveFoodsResponse.return.menuDetails.size();
```

But return in the above code is getting considered as return statement( truned blue in soap UI groovy script). I did not find any solutions for this online. Can anyone have any solution for this.

Note: I typed my code , please excuse if any syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

`xml.Body.retrieveFoodsResponse.return.menuDetails` returns a NodeChildren object, not a list. To get it to a list you can use `.collect()`

The xml has some mistakes that I fixed in my example:

```
xmlString = '''<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <retrieveFoodsResponse>
      <return>
         <menuDetails>foo bar </menuDetails>
         <menuDetails>foo1 bar1</menuDetails>
      </return>
    </retrieveFoodsResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''


def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
def dessert= xml.Body.retrieveFoodsResponse.return.menuDetails

assert dessert instanceof groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren

dessertList = dessert.collect()

assert dessertList.size() == 2
println dessertList
```